# How to get ,update all keys and its values from redis database in c#?

Tags: c#, caching, redis, servicestack.redis, nosql

I am using servicestack C# driver for connecting redis database which runs in 6379.
I want to retrieve(GET/READ) all keys and its values from redis database(which is actually cached).
I have to update two keys and its values in redisdb, is it possible to make an update without using list or hashtypes?

I want to know how to add numerous keys and values as well as update many at a time.

Answer (score 1):

With respect to Redis you want multiple update, multiple get and multiple add. You can use these commands for that purpose.

> [Mset](http://redis.io/commands/msetnx) - Multiple Set  [Mget](http://redis.io/commands/mget) - Multiple Get [Hmset](http://redis.io/commands/msetnx)- Multiple Set in Hashes. 
>   [Msetnx](http://redis.io/commands/msetnx) - Multiple Set if not exist.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way to retrieve all keys is to use the [SCAN API's](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis#scan-apis), e.g:

```
var allKeys = new List<string>();
using (var redis = redisManager.GetClient())
{
    foreach (var key in redis.ScanAllKeys())
    {
        allKeys.Add(key);
    }
}
```

You can get all values with `GetValues()` to return a List of values or `GetValuesMap()` to return a dictionary of key values, e.g:

```
var allKeyAndValues = redis.GetValuesMap(allKeys);
```

But depending on the number of keys you have you'll want to fetch them in batches.

Likewise you can set multiple keys and values with `SetValues()` e.g:

```
redis.SetValues(allKeysAndValues);
```